# creating a service endpoint for a service in eks

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

So I have a service running on an eks cluster.
It's of type LoadBalancer and annotated to create an nlb.

This is part of a migration we're having from fargate env to k8s. In the old environment, we used a service endpoint with that nlb to use PrivateLink.
Is there a way to create this with k8s automatically?

The whole process should be automatic - we use terraform, and I can't go and manually create the service over this. I also don't know how this would behave if I tamper with the app's service yaml - will it recreate the nlb? what then? (Using helm to manage it).

If there is no way to do this, maybe I shouldn't have k8s create the nlb, do this manually, and give the server some arn or other indication of the nlb to associate with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes AWS integration (the [cloud-provider-aws](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws) controller to be precise) currently can't provision/configure/pass VPC PrivateLink.

Solutions:

- as you mentioned - manual provisioning with the terraform and yes there'll be a problem upon a service replace,
- create a lambda function that will provision/decommission a PrivateLink on NLB creation/deletion. It might be triggered through CloudWatch Events/EventBridge - rule by the [`AWS API Call via CloudTrail`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html),
- file an issue - feature request in the

  - https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws
  - https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap